# question metric space

Tags: real-analysis

Let's say that for any point a in a metric space, and any $\epsilon$, we can find a point c(a), such that

$d(a,c(a))\le \Delta +\epsilon$

Is it then possible to find a point C(a), such that

$d(a,C(a))\le \Delta$?

Comment: how about $C(a) = a$?

Comment: Sorry I was a little unclear. a does not nececerraliy need to be a part of a subset C, where we can choose the points.

Comment: Can you specify which subset we are choosing the points $c(a)$ and $C(a)$ from?

Comment: You have a given point a, and a given subset C of the metric space. For any $\epsilon$, you can choose a c(a) from C, such that the first inequality is satisfied, C(a) is thought to be chosen from C  aswell. I think that maybe the second inequality may not every be satisfied, but we may have that $inf\{d(a,c): c \in C\}\le \Delta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not in general true. Take $C = (1,\infty)$, $a=0$, and $\Delta=1$. Clearly for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $c \in C$ with $|c-a| = |c| \leq 1 + \epsilon$, but for no element of $C$ is the distance to $0$ equal to $1$.

Comment: Thank you. The thing that really confueses me about these sorts of arguments is that I have seen arguments so that if both a and c are fixed, and we know that for all $\epsilon$, $d(a,c)\le \Delta+\epsilon $. Then $d(a,c) \le \Delta$. But I guess you cant use that argument when c is a variable.

Comment: @user119615 That is correct. It would be a different story however if $C$ were closed.

Comment: I see that in your example it would hold if C was closed, but do you in general need C to be compact for it to hold, or does it always hold if C is closed?